# How do I find out USB Speed from a terminal?

Tags: command-line, usb

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 . I am here to know is there any way to observe Writing & Reading Speed of the USB through the terminal .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `rsync` to give an approximation of your transfer speed, although it will vary depending on whether small or large files are being transferred and whether the destination is a slow flash drive or a fast external hard disk. For example:

```
rsync -avviu ~/Videos /media/Mik2

sent 874419803 bytes  received 149 bytes  4427442.79 bytes/sec
total size is 874312527  speedup is 1.00
```

(Also, if you open `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` and then connect your device you can see whether it is being set up for ehci (enhanced host controller interface), which supports USB 2 speeds. For example, the kernel log should state 'new high-speed USB device...using ehci_hcd'.)

Comment: I guess this anticipated the reason for the question, but it didn't answer the question as posed.

Answer (score 29):

I was curious about this as I had a SATA 3 SSD I wanted to use for  processing some video files (to keep i/o waits at a minimum) but I had only SATA 2 (3Gbps) ports available on the system, but also a USB3 port available.

You can determine the theoretical maximum speed of the port for each USB port with the command `sudo lsusb -vvv |grep -i -B5 -A5 bcdUSB`

The bcdUSB line returns the USB version of the port.

An example from one of my systems:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x8087 Intel Corp.
--
   Port 7: 0000.0100 power
   Port 8: 0000.0100 power
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
--

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
--

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10d5:5a08 Uni Class Technology Co., Ltd 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x10d5 Uni Class Technology Co., Ltd
--

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x8087 Intel Corp.
--
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0303 lowspeed power enable connect
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
--

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
--

Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:5106 ASMedia Technology Inc. Transcend StoreJet 25M3
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x174c ASMedia Technology Inc.
--

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
--

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
```

Or the quick and easy alternative of `lsusb -t` which provides output like this:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
```

Since the 5 Gbps available via USB3 was far closer to the 6 Gbps that SATA 3 is rated at I decided to connect the drive there on `Bus 004 Device 002`(via Asmedia USB3toSATA adapter). The results were quite satisfying.

Sources: 
This page

Experimentation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA
[How to find USB hub speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598022/how-to-find-usb-hub-speed?rq=1)

Comment: Is there anyway to correlate that information with a device node?

Comment: @Melab Seems obvious in most cases given the output of commands like `lsblk` and the content of files like [etc/mtab] If you have a new question, please feel free to ask using the [Ask Question button ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) in the upper right corner of the page.

Comment: @Flatron I'm [Always eager to help!](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16264/are-we-truly-eager-to-help)

Answer (score 21):

The `pv` tool allows you to view the throughput of the data flowing through it. After installing the package, you could run a command like the following to see the write rate:

```
$ cat /dev/zero | pv > /media/some_usb/tmp123

203.1MiB 0:00:02 [100.2MiB/s] [ <=>                   ]
```

For reading, perform the opposite operation using the newly-created `tmp123` file:

```
$ cat /media/some_usb/tmp123 | pv > /dev/null
```

Comment: This approach appears to give measurable & actual run-time results.

Comment: This only works on devices that are storage devices i believe.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is a little bit off the exact question since I am using *ubuntu 20.04*, I haven't tested it on other versions, but I think this may also be helpful.

This way is much easier for me:

1. **Run `gnome-disks` in terminal**, open the GUI interface. (You can also just search it in application list.)
2. **Click** the disk you want to test -> Device Options -> Benchmark Disk -> Start Benchmark

[image]

[image]

This shows speed of the USB drive, not [that of the USB port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101786/341192).

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
$ sudo lsusb -vvv
```

Then, have a look at the entries named *bDeviceProtocol* and *bInterfaceProtocol*

Comment: " bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only "
" bDeviceProtocol         0 "
means what ? But this answer not suitable to My Question .Thank you ,:)

Comment: Did you use the -vvv option? In my computer, there is a description associated to the 0 value: "0 Full speed (or root) hub"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/z2ESbyZL

Comment: You are right. This information seems to appear only on some devices.

Comment: @Raja, Run `sudo lsusb -vvv |grep -i -B5 -A5 bDeviceProtocol`. Then look at the entries listed as bDeviceClass Hub.

Answer (score 1):

i was wondering the same thing recently too but the other answers were not too satisfying. so i later found out that using `lsusb -t` will show if the devices is attached to the USB 3 root hub or USB 2 root hub and the device's speed.

```
    $ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

alternative, using dmesg, it will show when the device is enumerated as high speed or super speed

```
[274.010414] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd

[1478.495255] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
```