# How to find USB hub speed

Tags: usb

I have a 2008-era Macbook Pro, and according to the [specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP4?locale=en_US), both of its USB ports should be rated for USB 2.0 speeds of at most 480 Mbit/s.

However, when I run `sudo lsusb -vvv |grep -i bDeviceProtocol` the only USB hubs listed are for "full speed" which corresponds to [USB 1.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB), which is significantly slower topping off at 12 Mbit/s.

Am I misreading `lsusb` or is Ubuntu incorrectly treating my USB hubs like USB 1.0 and making them go 40 times slower than they should?

Comment: And if you `sudo lsusb` does it identify it as 1.0, 1.1 or 2.0 hub?

Comment: @douggro, It shows two entries of "Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub". I guess I'm misreading it? Strange the `-vvv` option shows something different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `lsusb -t`, it'll show all your USB devices in a nice hierarchy as well as the speed of each port.